# Schedule programs to run as admin in the background

Tags: anti-virus, administrator, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way I can schedule tasks to run on a Windows XP machine in the background with administrative rights?

For example if I want to run an anti-virus program at 3pm everyday with administrative rights (even if the user logged into the machine at the time is not admin -- or if no one is logged in). Is this possible and how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many AV programs have this fuctionality built in.  Symantec Endpoint protection can have scan scheduled at any time.  Most others would as well.

Can you provide more detail on the application you want to schedule?

Comment: I was just going to try it with SpyBot and ClamWin. How do I schedule the tasks to run with my admin rights?

Comment: Simply open the scheduled task window and click Add Scheduled Task Follow the wizard.  The last screen will allow you to enter credentials the app will use to run.  While this may work, you will not really know if you are infected as there is no alerting as with a managed application.